# Unable to create tables using hibernate JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I resolved this issue by checking weather I am creating my class inside com.example.PROJECTNAME and not out side of this package. By using all this properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=devesh007
spring.jpa..properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
server.port=8080
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this code

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl= true
```

also you need to delete second "." point in your code

```
spring.jpa..properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```